# Selecting max value from text field in sqlite

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a SQLite database on a Windows CE device. It has a column called product_code. The values stored in this column contain both letters and characters. The first character is dependent on the department in which the product is, for example for Draught it would be D, for Spirits S. A sample product_code column entry would be S124 or S09.

On the device, I have a form to add new products to the database. I want the form to be able to generate the next available product code. In order to do that, I need to select the max value of a product_code for a specific department (selected from a combo box).

I have tried using this:

```
stm = "SELECT MAX(CAST(product_code AS Int)) AS maxPCode FROM product WHERE department_description = '" + cmbDeps.Text.ToString() + "';";
```

But I get 0 in return. I have also tried:

```
stm = "SELECT MAX(CAST(product_code AS Int)) AS maxPCode FROM product WHERE product_code NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%' AND ISNUMERIC(product_code) = 1 AND department_description = '" + cmbDeps.Text.ToString() + "';";
```

But seems like ISNUMERIC() is not a function in SQLite? Is there any other way to get around this problem? I was thinking about possibly using replace(), but not sure if there is a way to strip any letter or if I have to have a condition for each possible department?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `product_code` contains a letter, you cannot cast it to a numeric value. The `SUBSTR` function allows you to strip off the first character, so to get the highest number in a department, you could use:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(product_code, 2) AS int)) AS maxPCode 
    FROM product 
    WHERE department_description = '" + cmbDeps.Text.ToString() + "'
```

**WATCH OUT** for SQL injection! Someone could enter a partial query into `cmbDepts` and view or delete your data! There are tons of resources about its dangers on SO and beyond.

Comment: I'll give this a go, but would this work as well: 
`SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(Description, 2)) AS maxPCode FROM DeviceLog WHERE department_description = '" + cmbDeps.Text.ToString() + "'`?
And can you explain what does the number 2 correspond to? Does it meant that SUBSTR strarts at position 2, skipping the first letter? Thanks

Comment: @user3468334 Updated my answer, added a CAST and changed the table/column names to your values, sorry :)

Comment: Yes, SUBSTR starts counting at 1, so `SUBSTR('AB', 2)` returns 'B'. It works with the `department_description` filter as well, even better than with a `LIKE`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much. I have noticed that some of the product codes have 2 letters in front of a number, but I suppose the best way to handle this, is a simple if else condition? It only applies to specific departments

Comment: @user3468334 I'm afraid that would be the best I could come up with as well - something like `product_code REGEXP '^.[\d]'` determines whether the second position is numeric, I don't know of any `ISNUMERIC` function in SQLite (that doesn't mean it does not exist!)

Comment: Thank god for forcing the manager to use master departments file! Thanks for all your help, much appreciated! On your note re:SQL injection. Not something that I am worried about as the app is only used locally with no access to the internet. Will keep in mind for future though!